# How to write a query on SQL to retrive second biggest date only once?

Tags: sql

I have a table (say, t1) with customerID (say, custID) and date (say, date) of purchase, so that there could be many customers making purchases on different days. I want to retrive the only two last purchases (two biggest dates) of each customer. I've recently started to learn SQL, so if this question is easy don't be too harsh)) Thanks in advance

Comment: What DB engine are you using?

Comment: Please tell us which DBMS you are using (Oracle? Postgres?)

Comment: Sorry for late response. Oracle

Answer (score 0):

should work in SQL server

```
select CustID , Date , row_number() over(partition by custid order by date desc) 
from t1 
where row_number() over(partition by custid order by date desc) <=2
```

or similar